# Django - display items from a collection inside a template

Tags: django

I am building an e-commerce store with Django, and I have added some products to a collection. I want to be able to display each collection separately with the products that have been added to it.

Here is my models.py code

```
#Collections model Fields
class Collections(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('collections', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Here is my Views.py:

```
def collectionsPage(request, slug):
    collections = Collections.objects.get(slug=slug)
    products = Product.objects.all()    
    context = {"products": products, "collections":collections,}
    return render(request, "collections.html", context)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('collections/<slug:slug>', views.collectionsPage, name="collections"),
]
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
{% for collection in collections %}
<form action="{{collection.products.get_absolute_url}}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="polaroid" style="background-color:white; border:none">
    <div>
      <img src="{{collection.products.imageURL}}" alt="iPhone image">
      <h3 class="container">{{collection.products.title}}</h3>
      <h4 class="container">{{collection.products.price}}</h4>
    </div>
  </button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you could use distinct to catch all categories from the products, and be advise because you used many-to-many field, they maybe some products in more than one cat

Comment: Hi i tried with distinct() and it didn't work. maybe I made an error somewhere else idk. do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: yes, instead of doing `distinct` form the product model objects, simply group all the objects of Category  Model. this will provide all available categories

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the problem as follows:

```
#Nothing to change in Models.py

#Views.py
def collectionsPage(request, slug):
    collections = Collections.objects.get(slug=slug).products.all() ###
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data["cartItems"]
    context = {"collections":collections, "cartItems":cartItems}
    return render(request, "collections.html", context)

#HTML code:
{% for product in collections %}
<form action="{{product.get_absolute_url}}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="polaroid" style="background-color:white; border:none">
    <div>
      <img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="iPhone image">
      <h3 class="container">{{product.title}}</h3>
      <h4 class="container">{{product.price}}</h4>
    </div>
  </button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```